# проверка авторизации laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel5

почему такой коде в контроллере не работает? выводит первую запись из базе

```
$id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find($id)->first();
        return view('profile.profile')->with(['profile' => $user]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать Auth прям в view:

```
{{ Auth::user()->name }}
```

Если все же хотите передать во view, то:

```
return view('profile.profile', ['profile' => Auth::user()]);
```

Comment: а как в контроллере вывести?

Comment: @Aslero обновил ответ

Comment: а как мне вывести тогда с привязанной таблицы {{ $profile->attributes->username}}

Comment: связь 1 к 1 у таблицы UsersAttributes и Users

Comment: @Aslero так и выводите {{ $profile->attributes->username}}

Comment: вот так тогда Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::$username (View: /home/e/extremje/sdprepod/study/resources/views/profile/referal.blade.php)

Comment: @Aslero dd($profile->attributes);

Comment: null и все, больше ничего не вывел

Comment: @Aslero значит что-то не так делаете=) проверьте данные в бд

Comment: все спасибо, затупил, у меня во второй не было данных(

Comment: а почему так не работает в контроллере
$id = Auth::user()->id;
$user = User::find($id)->first();

Comment: @Aslero выложите полный код+ код модели+ структуру бд=) А вообще, так делать вообще не стоит, у вас и так есть пользователь, зачем вам лишние запросы?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82957/discussion-between-ruslan-mirzapulatov-and-aslero).

Answer (score 0):

```
return view('profile.profile')->with(['profile' => auth()->user()]);
```